# Best way to communicate between 2 Fragments in different activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have a scenario with **Activity A** having tabs, **Fragment 1,2,3,4**. Here Fragment 2 opens **Activity B** which has multiple **Fragments 1,2,3,4**. Now from Activity B (Fragment 4), I want to send a result back to Activity A's Fragment 2 which was there in the background. What will be the best way to do that?

Currently, I am thinking to use Result API to open Activity B, and from Fragment 4 of Activity B, set Result somehow(now sure how). Should I set the result in Activity B first, which will then set the result for Activity A's Fragment 2?

Comment: This sounds like a nightmare. Why not stick to either single Activity architecture? Or at least multi-Activity without any more than one Fragment per Activity?

Comment: Maybe a singleton livedata variable?

Comment: That is equivalent to communicating b/w 2 Activities . So Result API  is the way to go .

Comment: @ADM thanks for your comment, and to communicate with Activity B from fragment 4. I should go with the shared view model?

Comment: You can use ResultAPI directly from Fragment ..  request code will be differ if you use in other fragments as well thats it .. You do not have to involve Activity in this unless you have to .. If you go with Single Activity Arch the Fragments Also have a resultAPI to send back data ..

Comment: @ADM I can open activity B without involving Activity A directly from my fragment, but while returning back, in this case, is there a way to directly communicate back, or does it have to go through Activity B first, which sets back the result?

Comment: Though Late, I use green bus event bus system to do so. The better approach is to use Single Activity and multiple fragments and no other activity should exit.

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to communicate between two Fragment A and Fragment B is through viewModel
ViewModel is created and share between two fragment , you set value from Fragment A and access the value using getValue() method in Fragment B .
ViewModel share same instance with both fragments

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 pretty simple solutions:

1. send an `Intent` from any activity or fragment (in your case, from Activity B Fragment 4), and set up an intent filter in your Activity A to receive that intent. You'll have to process that intent in Activity A's `onNewIntent()`, and then forward the data to whichever fragment you want
2. Use a lifecycle component, like `LiveData` to do it. You'll want to set either a Singleton class in Java or an Object in Kotlin, and then create the `LiveData` variable inside that class. And you can then set your Activity B to update that `LiveData` variable, and set your Activity A to observe it for changes

Comment: Second option `Singleton` and `LiveData` is a terrible solution ..

Comment: Why would you say that? It depends entirely on how the OP intends to use it. Depending on their app architecture, they may very well prefer posting data to LiveData and consuming it as it changes, rather than having to send intents and processing them, and all the lifecycle state management that comes with that